# Incorrect syntax near inserted value

Tags: java, sql, sql-server-2008, jdbc

I wrote this code to edit an existing table of my database called RegisterationForm. I'm using `Jframe` forms, but after running the program when I press the edit button, an error shows **`incorrect syntax`** near 'the word I've entered for sourceName'.

Even if I don't change anything and press edit, the error appears.
I tried debugging but I can't find out what's wrong.
`reg` is the name of the combobox I wanna choose an existing RegisterationForm id from to edit its records.

My code:

```
private void editActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
    if(l==0)
    {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(rootPane,"choose a number", WIDTH);
        return;

    }
    if(id.getText().equalsIgnoreCase(""))
    {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(rootPane,"retry", WIDTH);
        return;
    }


        String s="update RegisterationForm set id='"+id.getText()+"' , date="+date.getText()+" , sourceName="+sourceName.getText()+" , sourceCode='"+sourceCode.getText()+"'  where id='"+reg.getSelectedItem().toString()+"'";
        try 
        {
            DBlabprj.stmt.execute(s);
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(rootPane,"Done.");
            this.dispose();
            this.setVisible(false);

        } 
        catch (Exception e)
        {
              JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(rootPane,e.getMessage());
        }       
}                                        

private void showActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
    reg.setEnabled(false);
    l=1;
    String s="select * from RegisterationForm where id='"+reg.getSelectedItem().toString()+"'";

    try
    {
        DBlabprj.rs=DBlabprj.stmt.executeQuery(s);
        DBlabprj.rs.next();
        id.setText(DBlabprj.rs.getString("id"));
        date.setText(DBlabprj.rs.getString("date"));
        sourceName.setText(DBlabprj.rs.getString("sourceName"));
        sourceCode.setText(DBlabprj.rs.getString("sourceCode"));

    } 
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(rootPane,e.getMessage());
    }
}                                        

private void formWindowOpened(java.awt.event.WindowEvent evt) {                                  
    setDefaultCloseOperation(DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
    reg.removeAllItems();
    String s="";
    s="select id from RegisterationForm order by id";

    try {
        DBlabprj.rs=DBlabprj.stmt.executeQuery(s);
         while(DBlabprj.rs.next())
        {
            reg.addItem(DBlabprj.rs.getString("id"));
        }


    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(rootPane,ex.getMessage());
        Logger.getLogger(NewForm.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }        
}
```

Comment: Please include the actual error message and stack trace.

Comment: What's the value of `date.getText()`?

Comment: i highly encourage you too look into prepared statements. building a SQL string is problematic (as you are discovering) and open you up to SQL injection attacks. it's not that difficult and your code will be neater overall. you simply use ? question marks in the SQL instead of 'values' and set the values onto the prepared statement.

Comment: For date and string values you need to use single quotes, for eg : -date='"+date.getText()+" '..That's missing in your update statement

Comment: that doesn't matter, can you paste the edited post and try to get the query from profiler

Comment: @AswaniMadhavan Thanks, It worked. and I removed the single quotes for int types